How can I tell FastAPI to generate "securitySchemas" in openapi.json if the auth-method is dynamically injected?
I have an application that requires authentication. The authentication setup needs value from my app-settings and I want to use dependency-injection instead of a static global variable.
In the program below, you will see that the only route that properly advertises its need for authentication is the one that uses a static global (/static).
The other two (/dynamic and /dynamic-oidc) do not.
The code uses the HTTPBearer twice to demonstrate that the difference in behaviour does not come from the OpenIdConnect class. But rather from the way it's used.
What's worse is that the "Authorize" button will not be displayed if I only use the dynamic authentication objects.

My guess is that the dependency is evaluated lazily on first need. And at the time the OpenAPI JSON file is generated it's not evaluated.
Is there a way to fix this?
Application Code
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import (
    HTTPAuthorizationCredentials,
    HTTPBearer,
    OpenIdConnect,
)

BEARER = HTTPBearer()
APP = FastAPI()


def get_fake_settings() -> dict[str, str]:
    return {"oidc_url": "https://example.com"}


def get_dynamic_bearer():
    dynamic_bearer = HTTPBearer()
    # <configure the auth-mechanism>
    return dynamic_bearer


def get_oidc(settings: Annotated[dict[str, str], Depends(get_fake_settings)]):
    oidc = OpenIdConnect(openIdConnectUrl=settings["oidc_url"])
    return oidc


@APP.get("/static")
def static(
    auth: Annotated[HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, Depends(BEARER)]
) -> str:
    return repr((auth.scheme, auth.credentials))


@APP.get("/dynamic")
def dynamic(auth: Annotated[HTTPBearer, Depends(get_dynamic_bearer)]) -> str:
    return repr(dir(auth))


@APP.get("/dynamic-oidc")
def dynamic_oidc(auth: Annotated[OpenIdConnect, Depends(get_oidc)]) -> str:
    return repr(dir(auth))

OpenAPI JSON
{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "FastAPI",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/static": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Static",
        "operationId": "static_static_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Response Static Static Get"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "HTTPBearer": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/dynamic": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Dynamic",
        "operationId": "dynamic_dynamic_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Response Dynamic Dynamic Get"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/dynamic-oidc": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Dynamic Oidc",
        "operationId": "dynamic_oidc_dynamic_oidc_get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "Response Dynamic Oidc Dynamic Oidc Get"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "HTTPBearer": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    }
  }
}


To find security scheme, FastAPI looks at the object you pass to Depends(). And it should be inherited from SecurityBase to make FastAPI recognize that security scheme.
This is a related code from FastAPI sources:
(dependencies/utils.py get_sub_dependant)
    if isinstance(dependency, SecurityBase):
        use_scopes: List[str] = []
        if isinstance(dependency, (OAuth2, OpenIdConnect)):
            use_scopes = security_scopes
        security_requirement = SecurityRequirement(
            security_scheme=dependency, scopes=use_scopes
        )

Since you are passing function, mentioned condition is not True and FastAPI doesn't recognize this dependency as a security scheme.
It's probably a better way in your case to create a function, that creates FastAPI app. You can parametrize this function to setup security schemes
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import OpenIdConnect


def get_oidc(settings: dict[str, str]) -> OpenIdConnect:
    oidc = OpenIdConnect(openIdConnectUrl=settings["oidc_url"])
    return oidc


def get_app(settings: dict[str, str]) -> FastAPI:

    sec_scheme: OpenIdConnect = get_oidc(settings)
    APP = FastAPI()


    @APP.get("/dynamic-oidc")
    def dynamic_oidc(auth: Annotated[str, Depends(sec_scheme)]) -> str:
        return auth

    return APP


app = get_app({"oidc_url": "https://example.com"})


The downside of this is that the settings can not make use of dependency-injection. But your answer gives me the idea of writing a dependency as a callable class which depends on SecurityBase. I'll give that a try.
